# How to add text on click SVG rectangle using JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this SVG file... I want to add some text when clicking to rectangles and it shouldn't for the black one... Like when i click on any rectangle then it should be >>  g rectangle text /g

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="1200px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" enable-background="new 0 0 1200 800" xml:space="preserve">
<!-- <rect x="50.683" y="111.41" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1116.428" height="578.514"/> -->
<rect x="76.564" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="173.42" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="270.276" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="367.133" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="463.989" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="667.414" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="764.27" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="861.126" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="957.983" y="132.216" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.681" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="1054.839" y="132.216" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="41.042" y="351.442" fill="#FFFFFF" width="23.851" height="112.15"/>
<rect x="31.853" y="375.293" fill="#494849" width="1118.006" height="65.463"/>
<rect x="76.564" y="252.552" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="173.42" y="252.552" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the text node. The x and y of the text - in this case - is the center of the rect.

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
//the array of the rects with a white fill
let rects = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll("rect[fill='#FFFFFF']"));
//an array of true values as long as the rects array
let arr = Array(rects.length).fill(true);
//for each rect in the rects array
rects.forEach((r,i)=>{
  //get the position end the size of the rect (the bounding box)
  let bb = r.getBBox();
  //the center of the rect
  let x = bb.x + bb.width/2;
  let y = bb.y + bb.height/2;
  //on click
  r.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  //if there isn't already a text element there
    if(arr[i]){
    //add a text element
    let txt = drawSVGelmt({x:x,y:y},"text", svg)
    txt.textContent = i;
    arr[i] = false;
    }
  })
 
})

// a function to create a new svg element
function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {

  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}
```

```css
text{text-anchor:middle; dominant-baseline:middle}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="1200px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" >
<rect x="76.564" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="173.42" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="270.276" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="367.133" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="463.989" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="667.414" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="764.27" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="861.126" y="133.804" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="957.983" y="132.216" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.681" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="1054.839" y="132.216" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="41.042" y="351.442" fill="#FFFFFF" width="23.851" height="112.15"/>
<rect x="31.853" y="375.293" fill="#494849" width="1118.006" height="65.463"/>
<rect x="76.564" y="252.552" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.682" height="84.682"/>
<rect x="173.42" y="252.552" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="84.683" height="84.682"/>
</svg>
```

Observation: since the user can click many time on one rect I needed to add a condition. If there is no text node there create one, else don't.